# Angular js filter results condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have used filter in my app but want some results:

- If filter friend result is none show message that it **No freinds**
  works fine
- If filter friends of tracks result is none show message that **No
  tracks**

I want to hide friends too  when track result is none

I have created a sample app on plunker and displayed the respective message accordingly:

https://plnkr.co/edit/HaVGA4C2qnKjaBUOBlj0?p=preview

```
 <div ng-controller="repeatController">
   <p ng-show="results.length==0">
      No freinds
   </p>
   <p ng-show="play.length==0">
      No tracks
   </p>
   <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter friends..." aria-label="filter friends" />
   <input type="search" ng-model="t" placeholder="filter tracks..." aria-label="filter friends" />
   <ul class="example-animate-container">
      <li  ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results track by friend.name">
         {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
         <span  ng-repeat="data in friend.result | filter:t as play">
         <br> {{data.track}}.<br>
         </span>
      </li>
      <li  ng-if="results.length === 0"> 
         <strong>No results found...</strong>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

if no track is selected than how can I display the message **No tracks** only once just like:

taken from above code want this:

```
<p ng-show="play.length==0">
     No tracks
</p>
```

I want to display the message when the filter returns zero results, from all friends tracks i.e Search all `freinds.tracks` and if none are selected, then display the message.

Comment: it works, what is the issue?

Comment: @Sajeetharan want to execute the block when No tracks when no tracks is avaiable in all freinds. edited my question too

Comment: if array `play` doesn't exists, then `play.length` will be undefined. You need to check if array also was declared, so change it to: `ng-show="!play || play.length==0"`

Comment: Your plunker is not good. Please update it

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom filter. By evaluating multiple conditions in one filter it will gain 'performance'.

```
 $scope.filterData = function (item) {
 return (item.SECURITYCLASS === 90 || item.SECURITYCLASS === 93);
  }
```

On your view :

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:filterData">
{{::item}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Why not use the [angularjs filter function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) and use it like `angular.module('myApp', []).filter('name', function() { })`?

Comment: you use inline controller methods if this filter will run only for this controller, but if you want generic that can be used across the application use the $filter service

Comment: I think inline controller method is necessary here.